# Magento redirect after login

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I have a product page, in which users can login, like the website's facebook page and receive a discount for doing so.

I have everything working quite smoothly, except the mini-login.phtml file keeps redirecting the user to the account page.

Ideally, after login in, the user gets redirected to the page he/she was on. So that they can instantly click the 'facebook like' button after login in.

I've tried adding this code to the login form, didn't do anything.

```
<form action="<?php echo str_replace('login', 'loginPost', $this->helper('customer')->getLoginUrl()) ?>" method="post">
```

Is there a shortcode that'll allow me to redirect users to the same page they were on while loggin in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is managed from the Magento Admin area. Log in and navigate to:

```
System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Login Options
```

And select `No` for:

```
 Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it also stops my normal login page from redirecting. I only want to stop the redirect if the user logs in using the mini-login.phtml.

Comment: Ahh, I see! In that case I think you're only solution is to override the `_loginPostRedirect()` method in `Customer\controllers\AccountController.php` with a custom module. You could copy the existing function as a reference and simply modify the redirect URL, maybe by adding a POST variable to the login form.